# R arc.write error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, esri-geodatabase, sf

I am getting the following error while writing an `sf object` `dataframe` to a `GDB`. The dataframe imported is a feature class from a GDB brought in via the `sf` package. After some data manipulation I am trying to write the `dataframe` back into another `GDB` as a new `feature class/layer`.

I read in another post that `sf` does not support writing a `feature class` to a `gdb` so I had to use `arcgisbinding`.

UPDATE

The `arc.write` works on the sample `nc` dataset in the `sf` package but does not work on my dataset. I don't know if it matters but my sf object has more than `700,000` rows and `82` columns.

How can I fix this?

Error

```
Error in .call_proxy("arc_write", path, pairlist(data = data, coords = coords,  : 
  insert row failed
```

Code

```
    library(sf)
    library(arcgisbinding)

 arc.check_product()

product: ArcGIS Pro (12.8.0.29751)
license: Advanced
version: 1.0.1.244 
    
    arc.write("path/GDB.gdb/Feature_Class_Name", data = df, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Does it work if you just try and write the first 70 of your 700,000 rows (`data=df[1:70,]`)? Or just a few columns? Or maybe its a specific row or a specific column? Can you edit your Q to show: a) the thing you've got working with the `nc` data; b) more about your data - ideally a smaller version of it that still illustrates the problem (unless it is the pure size of the data, which is something you can investigate by trying to write smaller versions of it to see if that fails also or if there's a size limit you are hitting).

Comment: @Spacedman, yes you are right it does work on a `subset` of the `dataset`, so I beginning to think that big datasets are not handled well by the function thus causing this error.

Comment: @Spacedman, you know it's interesting to point out that the `dataset` which was modified in `R` and saved as a new `sf object` would just flat out fail every time I would try to `export` it as a `shapefile` in `ArcPro 2.8`. Thus, I had to bring the `feature layer` in `R` directly from a `gdb`.

Comment: Try doubling the subset size until you get a fail, then experimenting to see if it is a particular row. I don't have any ESRI products so can't try anything myself. Since its commercial software you could also try vendor help services (you pay enough for it...)

Comment: @Spacedman thank you, yes, I am already in touch with the `r-arc bridge` `ESRI` team on `Github`

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan Did you manage to solve this issue? I am getting the same error since updating from AcrgisPro 2.3 to 2.8
when trying to save sf or spatialpolygonDataframe to a gdb. > arc.check_product()
product: ArcGIS Pro (12.8.0.29751)
license: Advanced
version: 1.0.1.300

Comment: @nevilamos, try contacting author and look at this [question](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install/issues/108).